# Secure transfer of file to S3 using AWS PHP SDK

Tags: php, security, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

Are transfers of files into S3 made using the AWS PHP SDK secure against eavesdropping attacks by default, and if not, what do I need to do in order to make them so?

Comment: What you need to do is encrypting the files before transfering them to Amazon. Even if you use secure connections to S3, it's still readable for the server admins, NSA and hackers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default scheme for all services connected to by the SDK is HTTPS (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/configuration.html#scheme) so yes, *any* communication is secure against eavesdropping by default.